# jquery so link jumps to next named anchor

Tags: jquery, hash

Named anchors: `<a name="foobar" class="nextChart"></a>`

Links: `<a href="" class="next"></a>`

I'm trying...

```
$( "a.next" ).click(function() {
    var hash = $(this).next("a.nextChart").attr('href'); 
    location = hash;
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure a named anchor is the next sibling in your HTML document?

Alternatively, you can rewrite your code to:

```js
$("a.next").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var hash = $(this).parent().prev('.nextChart').attr('name');
  location = hash;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a name="foobar" class="nextChart"></a>
<div class="SOMECLASS">
  <a href="" class="next">asd</a>
</div>
<a name="foobar1" class="nextChart"></a>
<div class="SOMECLASS">
  <a href="" class="next">fds</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The repeating structure is... `<a name="foobar" class="nextChart"></a>
<div class="SOMECLASS">
<a href="" class="next"></a>
</div>

<a name="foobar1" class="nextChart"></a>
<div class="SOMECLASS">
<a href="" class="next"></a>
</div>` And I want to the first a.next to load the following a.nextChart.

Comment: As your snippet suggests they are not siblings. I'll update my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler answer would be to not listen for clicks, but to update the hrefs so the click does what you want it to.

```
$( "a.next" ).each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', '#'+$(this).parent().next('a.nextChart').attr('href')); 
});
```

Then, just by clicking on the link, it will go where it needs to go.

Comment: see comment I posted to first answer.